# Add Mailchimp interests fields into webform_mailchimp signup field

Tags: 7, webforms, emails

Currently I am using:

- mailchimp 7.x-4.9
- webform_mailchimp 7.x-4.x-dev
- webform 7.x-4.18

From [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_mailchimp/issues/2835917) I applied patch #2 to webform_mailchimp 7.x-4.x-dev module, and I can see the file `webform_mailchimp.module` has been changed. But it looks like on the Webform configuration page I don't see any changes?

In webform_mailchimp field configuration I have (see attachment):

**Mailchimp merge fields:**

```
NAME|field_naam
EMAIL|field_email
```

**Mailchimp interests fields:**

```
Gender|field_sexe
```

In webform component radio buttons `field_sexe` I have (see attachment):

```
Man
Woman
```

What I am doing wrong here?

I need to send the `interests fields` values like `Gender` and `Country` from my `webform_mailchimp` form to the [Mailchimp list Groups](https://mailchimp.com/help/getting-started-with-groups/) so I am able to [segment](https://mailchimp.com/help/getting-started-with-segments/) my Mailchimp list.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by going to the `webform component radio buttons field_sexe`. Inside this field configuration there is an option `Load a pre-built option list`. Select here Mailchimp's interests field: `Gender`.